# How to print only the columns next to a match using AWK

Tags: awk, match

Below is the sample file where I would like to print values in the columns next to the match..

```
$> cat sample.txt
DATABASE ORACLE, DB_TYPE Relational, OS OEL 5
VERSION 12.2.0.1

DATABASE MongoDB, DB_TYPE NOSQL, OS RedHat 7
VERSION 3.2
DATABASE MySQL, DB_TYPE Relational
VERSION 5.5
```

The lines starting with DATABASE and VERSION I joined them as following:

```
$> grep -i "^DATABASE\|^VERSION" sample.txt | sed 'N;s/,/\t/;s/\n/\t/'
DATABASE ORACLE  DB_TYPE Relational, OS OEL 5   VERSION 12.2.0.1
DATABASE MongoDB         DB_TYPE NOSQL, OS RedHat 7     VERSION 3.2
DATABASE MySQL   DB_TYPE Relational     VERSION 5.5
```

But now I would like to print only the columns next to DATABASE, DB_TYPE and VERSION and I did some thing like this.

```
$> grep -i "^DATABASE\|^VERSION" sample.txt | sed 'N;s/,/\t/;s/\n/\t/' |awk -v val1='DATABASE' -v val2='DB_TYPE' -v val3='VERSION' -F ' ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==val1 || $i==val2 || $i==val3) {n=i+1; print $n} }' 
ORACLE
Relational,
12.2.0.1
MongoDB
NOSQL,
3.2
MySQL
Relational
5.5
```

But I am expecting some thing like this

```
ORACLE      Relational      12.2.0.1
MongoDB     NOSQL           3.2
MySQL       Relational      5.5
```

Comment: Also tried, `grep -i "^DATABASE\|^VERSION" sample.txt | sed 'N;s/,/\t/;s/\n/\t/' |awk -v val1='DATABASE' -v val2='DB_TYPE' -v val3='VERSION' -F' ' 'BEGIN{RS="/n";OFS=RS} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==val1 || $i==val2 || $i==val3) {n=i+1; print $n} }' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <file | 
  awk '/DATABASE|DB_TYPE|VERSION/{printf "%s",$2 OFS; if(++c%3==0)print""}'

ORACLE Relational 12.2.0.1
MongoDB NOSQL 3.2
MySQL Relational 5.5
```

you can set OFS to tab or pipe to `column -t` for tabular formatting.

Comment: can you please tell me how to make the pattern matching NOT case sensitive..?

Comment: if you're using `gawk` you can set `IGNORECASE=1` in your `BEGIN` block.  Otherwise standard way of doing the same is `tolower($0)~/pattern/`

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this will work:
`grep -i "^DATABASE\|^VERSION" sample.txt | sed 'N;s/,/\t/;s/\n/\t/' | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "      " } /DATABASE/ {print $2,$4,$NF}'`

Searches for occurrences of DATABASE, output file separator (OFS) is tab - figure out how to insert a tab between the quotes for your particular OS